# remove /assets/ path from asset_host config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm using a cdn for my precompiled assets, and it's working with this asset_host config...

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://xxxxxx.xx.rackcdn.com"
```

and my asset paths are coming out

```
http://xxxxxx.xx.rackcdn.com/assets/application-xxxxxxxxx.css
```

When I need them to just be

```
http://xxxxxx.xx.rackcdn.com/application-xxxxxxxxx.css
```

What config value am i missing to remove the assets from the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change assets path by specifying
`config.assets.prefix = '/other/path-prefix'` in your `config/application.rb` or just for special environment in `config/environments/<env>.rb`.

To remove path completely set it to empty string:
`config.assets.prefix = ''`